# Tableau Server v2018.2 refusing to use port 80 despite it being open

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Windows Server 2016 that used to run Tableau Server v2018.1 (and a few versions before that); during this last update, I performed a backup and continued to wipe Tableau off the server (used the tableau-obliterate script which removed all things Tableau).

I then proceeded to install Tableau v2018.2 as a clean install, set up the configuration to use port 80 and started the server successfully.

However, I quickly discovered that Tableau moved the gateway to port 8000; I proceeded to review the ports to ensure nothing else is using this (this VM has nothing other than Tableau installed on it); I used TCPView and monitored the ports while the Tableau Server was running and Stopping/Starting; the only hint I found of something touching port 80 was the output of netstat, which showed an entry of TCP vizqlserver.exe with the state of `CLOSE_WAIT`.

I have tried manually setting the port through TSM configuration (run set, confirm with get, restart), TSM Settings import, and manually adjusting the configuration file for gateway, but Tableau just reverts back to port 8000.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening as again, nothing else has ever been on this server and nothing has changed since removing v2018.1 (which was running on port 80).

I tried to post this on the Tableau community forum, but 20 hrs later, it is still pending moderator approval :(

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent Windows update has been causing some port conflicts try this:

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/kb4338818-windows-update-causing-tableau-server-to-become-unstable

Comment: It would seem that this was indeed the issue. I ended up resolving the issue by removing Tableau (using the obliterate script), rebooting, and installing again. 

I do find it interesting that working with Tableau Support for 4 days did not yield this article...